# What is the best way to get a SAML identity provider (idp) to release userid without current domain

Tags: active-directory, identity, saml, federated-identity, shibboleth

I need my SAML IDP attributes to be independent of a domain name or authorize despite the domain name.

My SAML IDP response is:

```
<saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">Today999_@domain.com</saml:AttributeValue>
  </saml:Attribute>
  <saml:Attribute Name="urn:oid:2.5.4.42">
    <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">Today999_@domain.com</saml:AttributeValue>
  </saml:Attribute>
  <saml:Attribute Name="urn:oid:1.3.6.1.4.1.5923.1.1.1.6">
    <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">today999_@domain.com</saml:AttributeValue>
  </saml:Attribute>
  <saml:Attribute Name="urn:oid:0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.3">
    <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">today999_@domain.com</saml:AttributeValue>
```

is there anyway to fix this to:

```
<saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">Today999_</saml:AttributeValue>
  </saml:Attribute>
  <saml:Attribute Name="urn:oid:2.5.4.42">
    <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">Today999_</saml:AttributeValue>
  </saml:Attribute>
  <saml:Attribute Name="urn:oid:1.3.6.1.4.1.5923.1.1.1.6">
    <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">today999_</saml:AttributeValue>
  </saml:Attribute>
  <saml:Attribute Name="urn:oid:0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.3">
    <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">today999_@domain.com</saml:AttributeValue>
```

Should the SSO work despite what the domain is from the IDP? The Shibboleth authorizes based on the information provided, but the application does not accept the user id header. Is it that the user id is linked to the IDP provider?

Is the first output from the response the norm?

Comment: It appears that you are using Shibboleth for your IdP. If so, show us the relevant part of your `resolver-resolver.xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

Which values are returned in the attribute assertions depends on the configuration of the IdP.

Attribute Name 'urn:oid:2.5.4.42' has FriendlyName 'givenname' ... so returning domain part seems questionable.

Attribute Name  'urn:oid:1.3.6.1.4.1.5923.1.1.1.6' has syntax 'Domain-Qualified String' so one could expect to see domain specific values

Attribute Name 'urn:oid:0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.3' has FrienldyName 'email' ... so actually an email adress without domain part is illegal

Unfortunately I'm not a Shibboleth expert, you did not tell if 'SSO' or 'account linking' / federation does not work. I would not expect 'SSO' to fail because of the attribute values, but 'account linkin' could.